# What is the way to bootstrap Zend2 plugins properly?

Tags: zend-framework2

Currently I'm writing plugins like that:

```
namespace Lawyers\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin,
    Braintree as BraintreeSDK;

class Braintree extends AbstractPlugin
{
    protected $__initialized = false;

    protected $__pm;
    protected $__em;

    /**
     * Set Braintree config settings
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function init() {
        if($this->__initialized) {
            return;
        }

        $this->__pm = $this->getController()->getEntityRepository();
        $this->__pm = $this->__pm['ExternalPayment'];
        $this->__em =  $this->getController()->getEntityManager();

        $config = $this->getController()->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');

        \Braintree_Configuration::environment($config['braintree']['env']);
        \Braintree_Configuration::merchantId($config['braintree']['merchant_id']);
        \Braintree_Configuration::publicKey($config['braintree']['public_key']);
        \Braintree_Configuration::privateKey($config['braintree']['private_key']);

        $this->__initialized = true;
    }  

    /**
     * Create new entity for transaction
     *
     * @return \Lawyers\Model\Entity\ExternalPayment
     */
    protected function spawn() {
        return new \Lawyers\Model\Entity\ExternalPayment();
    }



    /**
     * New sales transaction
     *
     * @param mixed $Payer - person who pays this transaction
     * @param mixed $Source - source of payment: Lawyers\Model\Entity\Questions or Lawyers\Model\Entity\Lead
     * @param array $transaction - payment details:
     *      'amount' => '1000.00',
     *      'creditCard' => array(
     *          'number' => '5105105105105100',
     *          'expirationDate' => '05/12'
     *      )
     * @return mixed - transaction id or null
     */
    public function sell($Payer, $Source, $transaction) {
        $this->init();

        $data = array(
            'status' => 'pending',
            'amount' => $transaction['amount'],
        );

        # ....
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to initialize instance variables for plugins without using `$this->init()` in every call? I saw no constructor like method for plugins :(

Comment: Hmmm `__construct()` or maybe `__invoke()`?

Comment: `__construct()` will crash plugin logic, will try `__invoke()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding an initializer to the plugin manager

First have your plugin implement the `Zend\Stdlib\InitializableInterface`. (You'll also need to make the init method public)

```
namespace Lawyers\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin,
    Braintree as BraintreeSDK;
use Zend\Stdlib\InitializableInterface;

class Braintree extends AbstractPlugin implements InitializableInterface
{
    /**
     * Set Braintree config settings
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init() {
        // ..
    }

}
```

Then in your module bootstrap add the initializer.

```
<?php
namespace Lawyers;

use Zend\Stdlib\InitializableInterface;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)

        $sm = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $plugins = $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager');            

        $plugins->addInitializer(function($plugin, $pm) {
            if ($plugin instanceof InitializableInterface) {
                $plugin->init();
            }
        }, false); // false tells the manager not to add to top of stack
    }
}
```

NOTE: the intializer could be added by implementing the `Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ControllerPluginProviderInterface` in your Module class, and using the `getControllerPluginConfig` method, or via the `controller_plugins` key in `module.config.php`. However neither of those methods will allow you to place the initializer at the bottom of the stack, which is necessary here otherwise your plugin could potentially `init` before any other initializers have had a chance to inject dependencies.